# loading data from json to a listview in fragment

Tags: json, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am trying to display local JSON data to a fragment in a listview but whenever I run the app it crashes once I click on voir_of from main2activity

This is the XML of voir of where I want to show the listview filled with data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.root.afrochim.Main2Activity">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

this is the ticket

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Référence:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ref"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Date planifiée:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateplan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Article:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Entrepot:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/entrepot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Quantité d'article:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qte"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="unité de mesure d'article:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unitemes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="état:"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="20pt"
            android:layout_height="20pt"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/start" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="20pt"
            android:layout_height="20pt"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/stop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the note class

```
public class note {
    String ref = null;
    String date = null;
    String article = null;
    String entrp = null;
    Double qte = null;
    String unite = null;
    String etat = null;

    public note(String ref, String date, String article, String entrp, Double qte, String unite, String etat) {
        this.ref = ref;
        this.article = article;
        this.date = date;
        this.entrp = entrp;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.unite = unite;
        this.qte = qte;
    }

}
```

this is the main2activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentmanager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.of) {
            fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new firstfragment()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.comm) {
            fragmentmanager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new secondfragment()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

this is the first fragment

```
public class firstfragment extends Fragment {
    View myview;

    public firstfragment() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voir_of, container, false);

        return myview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<note> items = new ArrayList<note>();
        items = getdatajson();
        MycustomAdapter myadapter = new MycustomAdapter(items);

        ListView ls = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ls.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }

    public ArrayList<note> getdatajson() {
        ArrayList<note> list = new ArrayList<note>();//to verify
        String json;

        String refj = null;
        String datej = null;
        String articlej = null;
        String entrpj = null;
        Double qtej = null;
        String unitej = null;
        String etatj = null;

        try {
            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("data.json");//ouvrir fichier json
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read();
            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                refj = obj.getString("reference");
                datej = obj.getString("date");
                articlej = obj.getString("article");
                entrpj = obj.getString("entrepot");
                qtej = obj.getDouble("quantité");
                unitej = obj.getString("unité");
                etatj = obj.getString("etat");

                list.add(new note(refj, datej, articlej, entrpj, qtej, unitej, etatj));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public class MycustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<note> tab = new ArrayList<note>();//to verify

        MycustomAdapter(ArrayList<note> tab) {
            this.tab = tab;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tab.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return tab.get(i).ref;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater linflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view1 = linflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket, null);

            // parcour le tableau et remplir ticket by id
            TextView ref_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.ref);
            TextView date_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.dateplan);
            TextView article_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.article);
            TextView entrp_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.entrepot);
            TextView qte_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.qte);
            TextView unite_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.unitemes);
            TextView etat_view = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.etat);

            ref_view.setText(tab.get(i).ref);
            date_view.setText(tab.get(i).date);
            article_view.setText(tab.get(i).article);
            entrp_view.setText(tab.get(i).entrp);
            qte_view.setText((tab.get(i).qte).toString());
            unite_view.setText(tab.get(i).unite);
            etat_view.setText(tab.get(i).etat);

            return view1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post what log cat error say about your problem.

Comment: the build s successful but whenever i click "voir of" button the app crashes